# How to use python to load a web page in a delay?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I tried phantosJS,but it’s slow,taking 10s to get html, and every time I run the script, selenium would tell me it’s no longer supported.
Can I replace phantomJS with other tools?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a delay'...?

Comment: @Alichino Wait until the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case locate an element in the page source, could be anything, and then use WebDriverWait library and Expected Conditions.

In the end, this is what you should have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("[path to chromedriver]") # Or use any other browser
driver.get([your_URL])
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.TAG_NAME, 'title'))
```

However, it is said the `driver.get()` method DOES NOT wait for certain things, eg. ajax requests. You'd have to make sure the page is fully loaded yourself by either waiting for the presence of the elements you need on the page, or wait explicitly for the ajax requests etc.

Comment: Can I use modules like requests or urllib to make that happen?